# Add 1 year to the current date in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, task

Hi couldnt find anything here to help out with this one.

My company has a set of client folders that require a set of subfolders to be created at the end of each financial year. This is required to be a 2 digit representation of the year (ie - 14 Folder1 [for 2014] and so on).

I have a batch file that creates the folders every year, but have to modify the year every time. I am looking to schedule an auto mated solution, but i am stuck trying to add 1 additional year to the date. (as the folders need to be created at the end of the financial year, not calender year).

I am looking for a way to add 1 year to the current date. Here is my batch file so far. Any ideas anyone?

---

```
set YEAR= %DATE:~-2% + %DATE:~-2%

for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') do md "%%s\%YEAR% Folder1"
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') do md "%%s\%YEAR% Folder2"
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') do md "%%s\%YEAR% Folder3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
set /a YEAR=%DATE:~-2% + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set /a YEAR=1%DATE:~-2%+1
set YEAR= %DATE:~-2%%YEAR:~-2%
```

This is assuming that you want `1415` for the 2014-2015 financial year.

Are you aware that your construct will yield a <kbd>Space</kbd> before the string? Spaces are significant in string-assignments - on both sides of the `=`.

It's safer to use

```
set "YEAR=%DATE:~-2%%YEAR:~-2%"
```

for instance - the rabbit's ears in this format ensure that trailing spaces are omitted (that can cause chaos)